# Creating multiple environments from a vector in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble creating environments in R. I understand that you can create an new environment like `"Mar2015"=new.env()`. That works. However I cannot do this from a vector for some odd reason. I create this vector
`test=c("Mar2015","Sep2013")` and `test[1]=new.env()` does not work.

I am sure these are the same as I can use the unique command `unique(c(test[1],"March2015"))` and confirm that they are the same.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `test[i] = new.env()` you're trying to store an environment in a vector of strings; since an environment is not a string this code will cause an error.

You could create a named list of environments from `test` with:

```
envs <- sapply(test, function(x) new.env())
```

or

```
envs <- setNames(replicate(length(test), new.env()), test)
```

Then you could access your environments with `envs$Mar2015` and `envs$Sep2013` or equivalently `envs[["Mar2015"]]` and `envs[["Sep2013"]]`. Especially if you have a large number of environments you're creating, a named list is probably a better structure than individual variables for your environments.

If you really wanted to create a variable with each specified name, you could use:

```
for (x in test) assign(x, new.env())
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen from "for (x in test) assign(x, new.env())" ?  It doesn't change the test object.  Where do the new environments go?

Comment: @PhilGoetz that for loop creates new variables storing the environments. The names of the variables are the strings stored in `test`.